# Docker container can't connect to Redis

Tags: c, linux, docker, redis, hiredis

I have a Docker container running a C application using hiredis, which should write data to a Redis server exposed at the default address and port running locally on the same Linux device at `127.0.0.1:6379` .

The Redis server is running in a different Docker container. I start this container running, exposing port 6379 as follows : `sudo docker run --name redis_container -d -p 6379:6379 40c68ed3a4d2`

`redsi-cli` can connect to this via 127.0.0.1:6379 without issues.

However, no matter what I try, my container which should write to the Redis gets a Redis connection refused error from the C code all the time. This was my last attempt at running the container : `sudo docker run --expose=6379 -i 7340dfee8ea5`

What exactly am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `C` client is running inside a container, that means `127.0.0.1` points to the container itself, not to your host. You should configure the redis client to `redis_container:6379` as that is the name you have used when docker run the redis container. More about this [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name)

Besides, both containers need to be inside the same docker network. Use the following command to create a simple network

```
docker network create my-net
```

and add `--network my-net` to both docker run commands (redis client and redis server)

You can read more about docker network [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am definitely a noob with Docker. However, I still don't understand exactly what you mean by "You should configure the redis client to redis_container:6379 as that is the name you have used when docker run the redis container". Do you mean this is the name I should I should call it instead of Docker generating an identifier, for to add meaning only? Am I still correct with the -p 6379:6379 option to expose the port? Then which address must my c container write to then when the docker network is set up? Thanks.

Comment: `--name` serves two purposes. Identifying a running container giving more context than a bunch of numbers/human readable. And it also acts somehow as a dns allowing other network services inside the same docker network find your running ontainer using that dns name, as you do not know in advance which ip your container will be given. Redis clients (clients in general) needs the ip/dns and port of your redis server. So configure the client to point to the redis container name (dns) and the port you have configured.